# zsh give file argument without creating a file - syntax?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, syntax, zsh

Suppose I have have a program P which has a filename as argument. For example

```
P file
```

reads the file "file" and does something with it.

Now sometimes the content of "file" is very small, e.g. just one line. So instead of creating a file f with that line and calling

```
P f
```

I want to give the content of line directly as an argument to P. I don't want to write a wrapper for P.

Is it possible to do this in zsh? How would be the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
P <(echo "something something")
```

Same thing works for bash.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use process substitution if you already have a literal string or a variable. You can use a here string (which is a one-line here document).

With a literal string:

```
P <<< "f"
```

or, with a variable:

```
P <<< "$f"
```

The quotes can be omitted if you don't need to preserve whitespace.

This also works in Bash and ksh.

Comment: `cat <<<'foo'` works but `stat <<<'foo'` doesn't. What is `<<<` actually doing? Doesn't seem to be passing a filename to the program.

Comment: @mpen: Interesting. In Linux I get a `stat: missing operand` error, but in MacOS it works and calls the file `(stdin)` and outputs a 20 digit inode (larger than the number of inodes on my system). The Bash man page says this about here strings "The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the command on its standard input".  I believe it's implemented using a temporary file. `readlink` wasn't helpful and `grep -l . <<<foo` outputs `(standard input)` on both systems. I tried `strace` but I didn't see anything obvious.